# MATLAB Linux - How to increase font size Toolstrip?

Tags: linux, matlab

How do I increase the font size of MATLAB's GUI? I mean specifically the text of the 'Toolstrip', the menu items under the tabs HOME/PLOTS/APPS, which seem to be unaffected by modifying Settings > Fonts.

[image]

1. Editing my system font size did not solve the problem.
2. I suspect that it is currently [not possible](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/76495-how-to-change-the-size-of-matlab-2013-toolstrip-icons-and-fonts).